# C# reading memory allocated with AllocHGlobal with Span<T> instead of PtrToStructure?

Tags: c#, marshalling

I am not sure if this is even possible, but reading a lot about Span and started to play with BenchmarkDotNet and came to find out that my method is wasting a lot of memory of the heap.

I have to Interop with an external method which gives me a huge set of data. this method expects me to give a Pointer to memory to write the data to, and that is fine, I know it will use 20k of space (fixed) so I allocate memory with Marshal.AllocHGlobal(), get the IntPtr, and pass it to the external function using P/Invoke, and when done I free the memory with FreeHGlobal(), all that part is working fine and I dont expect to change anything.

Here is my dilemma, In my method, after I Invoke the external function and it writes the memory, I use Marshal.PtrToStructure() to read the results, I have defined the structure and I know where each value is, but I only care about a few of them.

I then read those values using myStruct.Whatever and assign those to my existing object, which is a managed and previously instantiated object.

I have come to discover that just by instantiating myStruct I allocate a lot of memory on the heap which after reading what I need and assign it to my other object I no longer need, and this method is executed every minute, so it turns out I am throwing to the heap more than I want to.

Is there any way I can read the memory that I already allocated with a Span and only reference to it and not create a new instance?

I was able to read byte by byte or int by int with Marshal.ReadInt but that is a lot of work and I have to remember each value offset.

Comment: within an unsafe context I guess it should be possible, but I'm not the best person to guarantee that.

Comment: Just use the `Span` constructor in `unsafe` code https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.span-1.-ctor?view=net-8.0#system-span-1-ctor(system-void*-system-int32) Alternatively, change your PInvoke to instead pass a `byte[]` array, which involves no copying.

Comment: @Charlieface can you tellme how should I declare it? I cant get it to work, And yes I am on a unsafe method already.
IntPtr myHandle contains the memory address and lets say I want to read 2000 bytes
Span<myStruct> myData = new(myHandle, 2000);  doesnt work

Comment: I don't know because you haven't shown us the native C definition and your C# `DllImport`. But like I said: change the `IntPtr somePtr` parameter to `byte[] somePtr` and pass a big array, it should just work

Comment: but i dont want to change the definition of my external function, I cant touch that part.  i dont even have access to the code for that. The function expects a pointer to free memory where it can write the data, Its of type IntPtr the signature is 

internal static extern unsafe bool myFunction(IntPtr memoryBuffer, int memoryLength);

Comment: Is your struct 20kb large? Or is it an array of structures? What is the signature of your native method? `MyMethod(void* ptr)`?

Comment: Does `Marshal.OffsetOf` help?

Comment: @shingo it helps me determine where each value is , yes, but I don't want to ready each value hard-coding the position, thats why I have the struct declared.
I just want to create this struct pointing to the address of memory already allocated , no matter if unsafe or not.

Comment: Use it to determine where the struct begins. Also please show an example of your struct, so we can discuss a practical problem.

Comment: I do know where the structure begins, well, it begins at the address of memory I allocated for it, the struct is pretty huge but its all the same... all fields of type uint and some of ushort, it has >68 fields and the total struct size is about 300B
I can potentially read the values using Marshal.ReadInt(myPointer,offset) but thats not the idea.

Comment: So you declare it `internal static extern bool myFunction( [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 1)] byte[] memoryBuffer, int memoryLength);` You don't need to change the C function, we just want to see its header definition.

Comment: @Charlieface I dont even have access to it, I just use the DLL that was handed to us already compiled.. 
Your idea is to give the DLL a memory buffer allocated on managed size instead of the unmanaged with halloc?

Comment: Yes exactly. In theory it should just work given the existing definition. Have you tried it?

Comment: No, I did not, but i will give it a try and see how it works.
However i was also able to create a span of the structure using myIntPtr.ToPointer() function, so that will also work